# Передача параметров от select2 через ajax

Tags: select2

Как передать в ajax запрос в качестве параметра строку для поиска и дополнительно идентификатор? Например, я хочу в первом поле select2 выбрать бренд автомобиля, во втором поле - модель, соответственно, я хочу выбирать из справочника моделей только те, которые относятся к этому бренду, получается мне надо передать еще и айдишник бренда. 
Пока что получается передавать только то, что набрано в строке поиска.
[Описание параметров плагина Select2](http://select2.github.io/examples.html#data-ajax)
в своей программе я использую 
[обертку на PHP от Картика](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2#usage-ajax)
Вот пример кода:

```
$brandUrl = Url::to('record/brandsearch');
echo $form->field($model, 'brandId')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'language' => 'ru',
    'options' => [
        'placeholder' => 'Укажите бренд ...',
        'theme' => \kartik\select2\Select2::THEME_BOOTSTRAP,
    ],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 0,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => $brandUrl,
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term}; }')
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('function(brand) { return brand.text; }'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('function (brand) { return brand.text; }'),
    ],
]);
```

Это поле корректно работает.
Я хотел бы добавить второе поле, в котором дополнительно в передаваемых ajax параметрах будет еще и айдишник из первого. 
Увы, нигде нет такого примера.

Comment: 1) покажите ваш текущий код. 2) select2 - это плагин или что-то иное?

Comment: @Apron63, отредактируйте свой вопрос, добавив ваш код и ссылку на плагин.

Comment: @Apron63, пожалуйста, вставьте ваш код в текст вопроса и приведите его к читаемому виду.

Answer (score 1):

У себя в проекте я это решил следующим образом:

1. Подчиненный `select2` не активен до тех пор пока в главном не выбрано значение из выпадающего списка;
2. На событие [`select2:opening`](http://select2.github.io/options.html#events) *вешаем* функцию которая будет получать значение из *главного* `select2` и формировать конечный `url` который возвращает необходимый список

Answer (score 1):

```
return {
    q: params.term,
    brand: brandId
}
```

Где brandId - id c первого селекта